# PHP JavaScript - Multiple checkbox choices into single phpmyadmin table

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have multiple check boxes in php for a single table in phpmyadmin, and im trying to find out how to put multiple values in a single table of the phpmyadmin (ex: Choosing Womers, Website, and Automail checkbox will put them together in a single CRP_SYS_AFFECTED table, with comas "Womers, Website, Automail").

[this is the checkbox interface that is used.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8WqO.png)

```html
<tr>
  <td><b>System Affected: </b></td>
  <td align='left'><input type='checkbox' name='aff' value='Womers' <?php if($input[69] == "Womers"){echo "checked";} ?>> Womers</td>
  <td align='left'><input type='checkbox' name='aff' value='LOS' <?php if($input[69] == "LOS"){echo "checked";} ?>> LOS</td>
  <td align='left'><input type='checkbox' name='aff' value='Host To Host' <?php if($input[69] == "Host To Host"){echo "checked";} ?>> Host To Host</td>
  <td align='left'><input type='checkbox' name='aff' value='Website' <?php if($input[69] == "Website"){echo "checked";} ?>> Website</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td align='left'><input type='checkbox' name='aff' value='SSWB' <?php if($input[69] == "SSWB"){echo "checked";} ?>> SSWB</td>
  <td align='left'><input type='checkbox' name='aff' value='Orafin' <?php if($input[69] == "Orafin"){echo "checked";} ?>> Orafin</td>
  <td align='left'><input type='checkbox' name='aff' value='Automail' <?php if($input[69] == "Automail"){echo "checked";} ?>> Automail</td>
  <td align='left'><input type='checkbox' name='aff' value='SID' <?php if($input[69] == "SID"){echo "checked";} ?>> SID</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td align='left'><input type='checkbox' name='aff' value='SSWBS' <?php if($input[69] == "SSWBS"){echo "checked";} ?>> SSWBS</td>
  <td align='left'><input type='checkbox' name='aff' value='PSAK' <?php if($input[69] == "PSAK"){echo "checked";} ?>> PSAK</td>
  <td align='left'><input type='checkbox' name='aff' value='Mirrorsys' <?php if($input[69] == "Mirrorsys"){echo "checked";} ?>> Mirrorsys</td>
  <td align='left'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='aff' value='Otheraff'
    <?php $mod_array = array("Womers", "LOS", "Host To Host", "Website", "Orafin", "Automail", "SID", "SSWB","SSWBS","PSAK","Mirrorsys");
    if(! in_array($input[69], $mod_array) && $input[69] != NULL){ echo "checked"; } ?>>
   <input type='text' name='other_aff' onkeyup='otherModCheck()' value='<?php if( ! in_array($input[69], $mod_array)){ echo $input[69]; } ?>'>
  </td>
 </tr>
```

if i checked only one, it works fine, but when i checked multiple, the one that goes into the database table are the one i checked the last.

Comment: when you're using checkboxes use different values for the `name` attribute. you can try using `name="aff[]"` too, this would give you an array of objects, then you have to either convert it to json or do your magic to fit in your db.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they all have the same name.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_checkbox.asp

Answer (score 0):

let me expand on my comment in order for you to get an array of all the checked checkboxes you can do something like this :

```
<form action="#" method="post">
  <tr>
    <td><b>System Affected: </b></td>
    <td align='left'><input type='checkbox' name='aff[]' value='Womers' <?php if($input[69] == "Womers"){echo "checked";} ?>> Womers</td>
    <td align='left'><input type='checkbox' name='aff[]' value='LOS' <?php if($input[69] == "LOS"){echo "checked";} ?>> LOS</td>
    <td align='left'><input type='checkbox' name='aff[]' value='Host To Host' <?php if($input[69] == "Host To Host"){echo "checked";} ?>> Host To Host</td>
    <td align='left'><input type='checkbox' name='aff[]' value='Website' <?php if($input[69] == "Website"){echo "checked";} ?>> Website</td>
</tr>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>


<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ //to run PHP script on submit
   if(!empty($_POST['aff'])){
    // Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
    foreach($_POST['aff'] as $selected){
     echo $selected."</br>";
    }
   }
  }
?>
```

one more thing that i forgot to add is that , if i'm correct you're bringing the value of `$input[69]` that is supposed to contain the array in which all these values are stored, in that case. what i see you're doing with  `<?php if($input[69] == "Womers"){echo "checked";} ?>` is that you are checking against one value at each line , you can try something like

```
in_array("Womers", $input[69])
```

this returns true or false. again this is only valid if your `$input[69]` is an array.

Comment: Do i have to add [] array on the code that connects it to the phpmyadmin too? '$input[69] = $_POST['aff'];
if ($_POST['aff'] == "Otheraff")
{
 $input[69] = trim($_POST['other_aff']);
}' because when i tried to use your if, when i checked on the database table, it only says "Array"

Comment: if understood your question correctly, you meant to ask if you need to have `[]` in your php side, the answer is no, the `[]` is only for your `html` to indicates that you're passing an array to the backend.

Comment: and with your edit answer, so i change from **<?php if($input[69] == "Womers"){echo "checked";} ?>** to **<?php in_array("Womers", $input[69]) ?>** ? or do i keep the echo checked on?

Comment: to make your life much easier you could do all that with javascript and jQuery though !

Comment: im starting to get what im getting wrong about the multiple checkbox, just a minor faultlines left, thank you for your help! this is a project my teacher asked me to do using php and html.  once again, thank you!

Comment: more than happy to help, if this answer helped you , check it so others can use this when they have similar questions.